# How to set maps api a floor on a multi-floor building in street view?

Tags: api, google-maps, maps

How do you set a floor on a multi-floor building in street view? I've looked thought the api and can't see a way to do it. Any help greatly appreciate, thanks.

Comment: What api are you referring to?

Comment: I was tring to use the javascript one as its for a web page. Maybe just using and iframe might be the only way to do it.

Comment: Are you referring to Google Maps or Bing Maps or some other mapping api?  Add that tag to your question and you may get some better responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify a level when publishing a panorama using the google street view publish api.

```
The following fields are valid:

pose.heading
pose.latLngPair
pose.pitch
pose.roll
pose.level
pose.altitude
connections
places
```

You have to first publish the photo, and then update it.
See the docs here :
https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/update
https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchUpdate